# Simple contact form not showing validation errors or sending the message

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple contact form in Laravel 5. If I submit it with empty fields, the page reloads but it doesn't show me the error messages of the validation. If I fill in the form and submit, I get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140: View [emails.message] not found.

That's because I don't have such view, I'm not sure what to put in it and Laravel's documentation is not clear on the subject:

> The first argument passed to the send method is the name of the view that should be used as the e-mail body.

Not sure what that means.

Routes

```
Route::get('contact','HomeController@contactus');
Route::post('contact_request', 'HomeController@contactRequest');
```

HomeController

```
public function contactus()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $count = Cart::count();
        } else {
            $count = 0;
        }

        $contact = Contact::all();

        return view('contact')->with('contact', $contact)->with('count', $count);
    }

public function contactRequest() {

        if (Auth::check()) {
            $count = Cart::count();
        } else {
            $count = 0;
        }

        $contact = Contact::all();

        //Get all the data and store it inside Store Variable
        $data = Input::all();

        //Validation rules
        $rules = array (
            'name' => 'required', 
            'email' => 'required|email',  
            'message' => 'required|min:5'
        );

        //Validate data
        $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);

        //If everything is correct than run passes.
        if ($validator -> passes()){

            Mail::send('emails.message', $data, function($message) use ($data)
            {
                //$message->from($data['email'] , $data['first_name']); uncomment if using first name and email fields
                $message->from('feedback@gmail.com', 'feedback contact form');
                //email 'To' field: cahnge this to emails that you want to be notified.
                $message->to('feedback@gmail.com', 'John')->cc('feedback@gmail.com')->subject('feedback form submit');

            });
            // Redirect to page
            return view('contact')
                ->with('message', 'Your message has been sent. Thank You!');


            //return View::make('contact');
        }else{
            //return contact form with errors
            return view('contact')
                ->with('error', 'Feedback must contain more than 5 characters. Try Again.')
                ->with('contact', $contact)
                ->with('count', $count);
        }
    }
```

View

```
<h1 class='siteh1'>Contact Us</h1> 
<hr class='sitehr'/>
<div class="col-md-6 siteleft">
<h2 class='siteh2'>Contact Info</h2>
<div class='contaddr'><label>Address:</label> {!!$contact[0]['Address']!!}</div>
<div class='contphone'><label>Phone:</label> {!!$contact[0]['Phone1']!!} | {!!$contact[0]['Phone2']!!}</div>
<div class='contemail'><label>E-mail:</label> {!!$contact[0]['Email']!!}</div>
<div class='contfollow'><label>Follow us:</label><p>
                            <a href="{!!$contact[0]['Facebook']!!}"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                            &nbsp;<a href="{!!$contact[0]['Youtube']!!}"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
                            &nbsp;<a href="{!!$contact[0]['Skype']!!}"><img src="images/skype.png" alt="Skype"></a>
                            &nbsp;<a href="{!!$contact[0]['Google']!!}"><img src="images/gplus.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
                        </p></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<p class='siteright'>
Get in touch with us
</p>
    <div class='contform'>
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'HomeController@contactRequest', 'METHOD' => 'PUT']) !!}

        <ul class="errors">
            @foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)

            @endforeach
        </ul>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form:: text('name', '', array('placeholder' => 'Your Name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'contname', 'rows' => '4' ))  !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form:: text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Your Email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'contemail', 'rows' => '4' )) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form:: text('phone', '', array('placeholder' => 'Your Phone', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'contphone', 'rows' => '4' )) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form:: textarea('message', '', array('placeholder' => 'Message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'contmessage', 'rows' => '4' )) !!}
        </div>



    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
        {!! Form:: close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your validation is failing because you are not passing in data to validator. I see $data, but where are you getting it from? create a view in emails.message. `Mail` function passes the `$data` to the view for you. You just have to echo it.

Comment: `$data` is coming from `$data = Input::all();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails are just blade templates, and the dots note the directory structure. Blade templates are stored in `resources/views`, so in this case, `emails.message` will cause Laravel to look in `resources/views/emails` for the file `message.blade.php`.

Create the file `resources/views/emails/message.blade.php` with the content of your message.

All of the data from the form is being passed (via the `$data` argument), so you should be able to access it in the message view file like this.

```
Hello {{ $name }}, your phone number is {{ $phone }}
```

As far as the main view template goes, your error handling code should be:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $message)
    <li>{{ $message }}</li>
@endforeach`
```

Comment: I created it and added `{{ $name }} {{ $phone }} {{ $email }} {{ $message }}` but got this error on submissions `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\techmine\resources\views\emails\message.blade.php)`

Comment: I suspect this is a conflict with the variable `$message`, which is the email message class itself being injected into the view. You could rename your `Form::textarea('message'...` to `Form::textarea('body'...` and use {{ $body }} in the blade template.

Comment: I just tried that and I got a new error, which is good. `Call to a member function all() on string` which I think they're referring to this line in the contact view `@foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)`

Comment: You're passing a string (`->with('error', 'Feedback must contain...`) for the `errors` value, when the view is expecting an array. Try `->with('error', ['Feedback must contain...'])` (wrap your string in [] to create the array).

Comment: I amended the answer to include an update to the error handling code that is incorrect.

Comment: I tried that earlier, didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88614/discussion-between-ericmakesstuff-and-halnex).

Comment: thank you for your time but I think I solved it. I had to pass `->withErrors([])` and now validation is working and when I fill the form, I get `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` which I assume it's because I don't have a local mailserver.

Comment: Are you still in the chat?